# Iterating over LLM models does not work in LangChain

Tags: python, openai-api, huggingface, langchain

I am trying to instantiate LangChain LLM models and then iterate over them to see what they respond for same prompts.

```
from langchain.llms import OpenAI, HuggingFaceHub
from langchain import PromptTemplate
from langchain import LLMChain
import pandas as pd

bool_score = False
total_score = 0
count = 0

template = "{context} {prompt}"
prompt = PromptTemplate(template=template, input_variables=['context', 'prompt'])

llms = [{'name': 'OpenAI', 'model': OpenAI(temperature=0)},
        {'name': 'Flan', 'model':  HuggingFaceHub(repo_id="google/flan-t5-xl", model_kwargs={"temperature": 1e-10})}]

df = pd.read_excel(r'data/Test2.xlsx')

for llm_dict in llms:
    llm_name = llm_dict['name']
    llm_model = llm_dict['model']
    chain = LLMChain(llm=llm_model, prompt=prompt)

    df.reset_index()
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        context = (row['Context']).replace("\n", " ")
        prompts = (row['Prompts']).split("\n")
        labels = (row['Labels']).split("\n")
        for prompt, label in zip(prompts, labels):
            print(f"Context: {context}\nPrompt:{prompt}\nLabel: {label}")
            keywords = {'context': context, 'prompt': prompt}
            print(f"Response: {chain.run(keywords).strip()}")
            if bool_score:
                str_score = input('Score? 0 for Wrong, 1 for Perfect : ')
                total_score += float(str_score)
                count += 1

    if count:
        print(f"LLM score for {llm_name}: {total_score / count}")
```

The first LLM model runs well, but for the second iteration, gives following error:

```
    chain = LLMChain(llm=llm_model, prompt=prompt)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "pydantic\main.py", line 341, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for LLMChain
prompt
  value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)
```

Am I missing something? in dictionary declarations?

Data file Test2.xls looks like:
[image]

Comment: Source code and data can be seen at https://github.com/yogeshhk/SaaSGPT/tree/master/src/bAbi_tasks

Answer (score 0):

'prompt' variable was getting confused I guess. I changed the second declaration as 'query' and it seems to work.

```
template = "{context} {query}"
prompt = PromptTemplate(template=template, input_variables=['context', 'query'])

llms = [{'name': 'Flan', 'model': HuggingFaceHub(repo_id="google/flan-t5-small", model_kwargs={"temperature": 1e-10})},
        {'name': 'OpenAI', 'model': OpenAI(temperature=0)}]

df = pd.read_excel(r'data/Test2.xlsx')

for llm_dict in llms:
    llm_name = llm_dict['name']
    llm_model = llm_dict['model']
    chain = LLMChain(llm=llm_model, prompt=prompt)

    df.reset_index()
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        context = (row['Context']).replace("\n", " ")
        queries = (row['Queries']).split("\n")
        labels = (row['Labels']).split("\n")
        for query, label in zip(queries, labels):
            print(f"Context: {context}\nQuery:{query}\nLabel: {label}")
            keywords = {'context': context, 'query': query}
            print(f"Response: {chain.run(keywords).strip()}")
            if bool_score:
                str_score = input('Score? 0 for Wrong, 1 for Perfect : ')
                total_score += float(str_score)
                count += 1

    if count:
        print(f"LLM score for {llm_name}: {total_score / count}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to assign prompt inline instead of variable, I have tried it, it works.

```
chain = LLMChain(llm=llm_model, prompt=PromptTemplate(template=template, input_variables=['context', 'prompt']))
```